# Pandas GroupBy query

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in pandas which looks like the following:
[Snapshot of my pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaSjm.png)

Now I want the data frame to be transformed like below wherein attribute 'category' get concatenated separated by a delimiter for each customerid based on sorted date value(%m/%d/%Y). The order with earlier date has its category listed first for the corresponding customer id.

[Desired/Transformed data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5WEq.png)

Comment: Can age differ for the same customer, since you have dates associated with each row? How should it be handled in the transformed DataFrame?

Comment: @ALollz age wold not differ. date column should be dropped at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df = (df.sort_values(['customerid','Age','Date'])
        .groupby(['customerid','Age'])['category']
        .agg(', '.join)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   customerid  Age               category
0           1   10  Electronics, Clothing
1           2   25      Grocery, Clothing
```